# Can't create Django Custom User from Django admin page

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I've created a custom user model named User that inherits from AbstractUser to add two additional fields for two-factor authentication (otp_base32 and otp_auth_url). Additionally,
I've defined a custom manager (CustomUserManager), which extends BaseUserManager and generates otp_base32 otp_auth_url fields of User using the pyotp library.
Now, when I create a User from Django admin page, otp_base32 and otp_auth_url fields are not generated, however I have defined such functionality in Custom Manager.

models.py

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from .managers import CustomUserManager


class User(AbstractUser):
    otp_base32 = models.CharField("2FA base32", max_length=255, blank=True)
    otp_auth_url = models.CharField("2FA URL", max_length=255, blank=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = CustomUserManager()
```

managers.py

```py
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
import pyotp


class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, username, password, **extra_fields):
        if not username:
            raise ValueError(_("The Username must be set"))
        user = self.model(username=username, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        otp_base32 = pyotp.random_base32()
        user.otp_base32 = otp_base32
        user.otp_auth_url = pyotp.totp.TOTP(otp_base32).provisioning_uri(
            name=username, issuer_name="starglassonline.uz")
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_staff", True)
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_superuser", True)
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_active", True)
        if extra_fields.get("is_staff") is not True:
            raise ValueError(_("Superuser must have is_staff=True."))
        if extra_fields.get("is_superuser") is not True:
            raise ValueError(_("Superuser must have is_superuser=True."))
        return self.create_user(username, password, **extra_fields)
```

admin.py:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import User

admin.site.register(User)
```

I want to 2FA-fields be generated when I create a user from Django admin page. How it can be solved?